# Codeigniter Undefined Variable on status

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

i have login form like this

[image]

log in to the application, it shows menu like this
[image]

it went fine until i click some menu, then it shows
[image]

here is the controller of the link that i clicked
i thought `keuangan` was already on the menu, but why does the `keuangan` not appear when i click some link of the menu ?

```
 function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'QB Cash Advance Settlement';
    $this->load->view('menu',$data);
    $this->load->view('v/vcas');
}
```

here is the `c_menu` controller

```
function index()
{
    $data['title'] = "QB Dashboard";
    $data['jabatan'] = "Keuangan";
    $this->load->view('menu',$data);
    $this->load->view('body');
}
```

here is the menu_view

```
<div id ="user">Selamat datang, <?php echo $jabatan; ?></div>
```

the login controller

```
function login()
{   
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $jabatan = $this->input->post('jabatan');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','alpha_numeric|trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

     if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
     {
         $this->load->view('login');
 }
  else
 {

         if($jabatan == 'keuangan')
         {
                 redirect('c_menu','refresh');
         }
         else if ($jabatan == 'hd')
         {
             echo $jabatan;
         }
         else
         {
             echo $jabatan;
         }
 }
```

do i need to declare `$data['title'] = 'keuangan'` in every controller/index ?

Comment: Please add the view code as well.  Particularly the one with the Line Number 12 that is generating the error.

Comment: The menu loads fine initially, but then you click a link on it and get this error.  What is the link?  Doesn't it route to somewhere other than the controller's index() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you bind into the view will not persist.  So it's there when you load the menu the first time because you set it in the controller here:

```
$data['jabatan'] = "Keuangan";
$this->load->view('menu',$data);
```

But then when you click on the link it goes to a different controller.

```
$data['title'] = 'QB Cash Advance Settlement';
$this->load->view('menu',$data);
```

`$data['jabatan']` is not set in this controller before binding `$data` into the view, so that's why it is undefined.

Comment: yeah, so we need to define the the `$data['jabatan'] = "Keuangan";` in every index / different controller ?

Comment: Either that or you can do something like persist it in the session (and then bind a variable retrieved from the session into the view in every controller that needs it.  CodeIgniter has custom session stuff so you can look over that in their docs.